# System.Runtime vs mscorlib in a CompositeFont

Tags: wpf, .net-core, fonts, .net-4.0

We are in the process of migrating our WPF application from .NET Framework to .NET Core 3.1. 
While working on this, I had to exchange all references in xaml from `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` to `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"`. Makes perfect sense, `mscorlib` is for .NET Framework and `System.Runtime` is for .NET Core. Read more [here](https://dot-net-core.programmingpedia.net/en/tutorial/5994/understanding-system-runtime-vs-mscorlib).

Starting up the application I found out there was an issue with a composite font not being loaded. Because I just replace `mscorlib` with `System.Runtime`, the file would look like this:

```
<FontFamily xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/composite-font"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime">

    <!-- Name mapping -->
    <FontFamily.FamilyNames>
        <system:String x:Key="en-US">My Font</system:String>
    </FontFamily.FamilyNames>
    <FontFamily.FamilyMaps>
    ...
    </FontFamily.FamilyMaps>
</FontFamily>
```

But I still had problems. So I changed this one file back to use mscorlib like this:

```
<FontFamily xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/composite-font"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <!-- Name mapping -->
    <FontFamily.FamilyNames>
        <system:String x:Key="en-US">Cabo Font</system:String>
    </FontFamily.FamilyNames>
    <FontFamily.FamilyMaps>
    ...
    </FontFamily.FamilyMaps>
</FontFamily>
```

And now everything works perfect.

Anyone with a good explanation of why this is?

Comment: _there was an issue with encoding or a font related issue_ Could you please explain a little bit, what kind of issue did you get here?

Comment: The problem was that the composite font was not being loaded. There are some unicode mapping to different fonts. But the main issue was that it was not loaded.

Comment: Did you have `en-US` culture enabled in your app as default?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. Everything works fine right now. What I want to know is why it works. Why does it not work referencing `System.Runtime` but it works using `mscorlib`.

Answer (score 1):

> While working on this, I had to exchange all references in xaml from `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` to `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"`

You shouldn't have to do this since any reference to `mscorlib` is type forwarded to `System.Runtime` automatically: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/708.

This means that the very same markup that you used when targeting the .NET Framework should also work when you target .NET Core.

Comment: Refering to `clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib` will actually give designtime errors, but no build or runtime errors. This must be a bug in Visual Studio.